# How much diskspace will a complete download of Maven Central Repository consume?

Tags: maven

This is good info: https://search.maven.org/stats
but not enough.

Assume I download the complete Maven Central Repository,
how much diskspace will it consume ?

Answer (score 0):

#### How much disk space does the Maven Repository consume?

> Approximately 10MB is required for the Maven installation itself. In addition to that, additional disk space will be used for your local Maven repository. The size of your local repository will vary depending on usage but expect at least 500MB.

Source: [Maven – Download Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Note that Maven 3.3+ requires JDK 1.7 or above to execute - so you will need to download and install Java as well. See [Windows System Requirements for JDK and JRE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/windows-system-requirements.html#disk-space-32).

Comment: Clarification: I asked about the size, should I download the "whole" Maven Central Repository in 2022.  

In 2016 is was > 2.5 TB
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-1185  
"As far as size goes, the last time I looked Maven Central occupied > 2.5TB on disk."

Comment: I couldn't find any more recent figures.

Comment: From same link, in 2020:  "Maven Central, IIRC, is currently on the order of 15TB, and that's only for release versions. Snapshots are not hosted Maven Central (repo1.maven.org)."